# MongoDB Schema Evolution Best Practice

Tags: mongodb

In my MongoDB application (written with C#) I have a document for which I expect later extensions, which means fields will be added later when the database is already in productive use.

Extending actually is not a problem as long as the new versions of my application won't declare an additional data field to be mandatory. So I will define a default then and not existing data will be ok.

But there are several applications accessing this database and one of them may not be updated and thus not know the added data field.

By default an application will run into an exception in this case (reading an unknown data field). For this case there is designated a class attribute [BsonIgnoreExtraElements], which leads into ignoring this unknown field.

**But if this older application will write back a document read incompletely, the field which was added to the database document by the newer application will get lost.**

The only solution I know to avoid this is to use typeless data (either BsonDocument or even only a JSON string).

**Is there another solution? Is there a best practice for this?**

Thanks a lot in advance for all answers and comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the solution, which is fantastically easy!

Add a field of type BsonDocument and tag it with the attribute [BsonExtraElements]. This leads into additional fields to be stored in this field. In principal they could be accessed in a generic way, but that's not the intention. It will just keep all additional data unknown to this (older) version of the client and write it back as it is.

```
// This field will be set with all data which is not known by this class (makes this class upwards-compatible)
[BsonExtraElements]
public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
```

(The [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] attribute can be omitted then.)

Comment: This is kind of clever but I am still trying to wrap my head around it Nick. Can you kindly expand on the concept here a little? Thanks!

Comment: @user3919920: The field marked with [BsonExtraElements] attribute will receive all fields which are unknown to this C# class. Its type BsonDocument is able to keep all kind of data in a generic way. Different clients versions may know or not know added data fields, so the older version will have the data in this field and write it back as it is when writing.